# Why `show` overloading doesn't work if called `show` first?

Tags: julia

Normally

```
julia> Base.show(io::IO, a::Int) = print(io, "xx")
show (generic function with 98 methods)

julia> show(2)
xx
```

It is overloaded correctly.

However, if I call `show` before overloading, it doesn't overload, nor gives any warning.

```
julia> show(1)
1
julia> Base.show(io::IO, a::Int) = print(io, "xx")
show (generic function with 98 methods)

julia> show(2)
2
julia> Base.show(2)
2
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a long outstanding issue,  [#265](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/265).
When you call `show(2)`, it will in turn call `show(STDIN, 2)`, but those functions had already been  compiled when you called `show(1)`, and due to the issue, the dependent function `show(::Int)` will not be recompiled.

Of course, you should rarely need to change a behavior after it had been relied upon in the code. In general, there's no telling how you might break existing code such as the `Base` library by changing behavior that is already there. Adding behavior for new types is fine, on the other hand.